# MySQL 5.6 won't start or log to a log file

Tags: mysql

I needed to use a mySQL 5.6 feature (on Ubuntu), so I uninstalled the version I got from apt-get and downloaded and compiled the mySQL 5.6 source code. It installed fine but I can't get mysqld to start. When I run the command `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld` I get the following output:

```
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-02-25 10:03:47 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-02-25 10:03:48 11597 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-02-25 10:03:48 11597 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-02-25 10:03:48 11597 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 2431209696
2013-02-25 10:03:48 11597 [ERROR] Aborting
```

And then it prints a bunch of messages about various plugins shutting down. I want to know why it is failing to start, so I am trying to get it to log more specific error messages. I tried creating the file /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys but that just made it print other errors when I tried to start it, so I deleted that file again. I looked in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and uncommented the lines that say:

```
 general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
 general_log             = 1
```

And then I created the file /var/log/mysql/mysql.log, chowned it to mysql:adm, and tried starting it again, but it won't write to the file.

Any advice on what to try from here? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to send your *cnf configuration file ?

Comment: The error about "/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys" seems to be the problem. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/102875/ysql-5-5-starts-and-then-instantly-stops-on-ubuntu-10-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Wagner's comment was correct. I was able to fix the problem by running the commands `sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys` and `sudo chown mysql:mysql /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/102875/ysql-5-5-starts-and-then-instantly-stops-on-ubuntu-10-10 for more information.